# How to convert text to a function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a text string that is correctly formatted as a function and I would like to convert it to an actual function.  The text string looks like:

```
function object_123(){
   object_123_Action();
   my_clicked(obj);
}
```

Apart from the word "function" and `{}`; all other text is dynamically constructed. i.e. It may never contain `object_123_Action()`, however, it will be something similar, basic function calls.  The only issue will be the `obj` will need to be the object that the function is assigned to.

Basically, I need:

```
this.func = eval(func_txt); //to actually work.
```

Where func_txt is:

```
function object_123(){
   object_123_Action();
   my_clicked(this);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the `eval` call? It actually works when you wrap the `function(){}` in `()`, ie. `eval("(function(a, b){ return a + b; })")(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains a function declaration.

When evaluated, it creates a `object_123` variable in the scope of eval (which you can then call later) and returns nothing.

If you want to assign the function to `this.func` then you need to convert the declaration into a function *expression*. You can do that by wrapping it in parens.

```
this.func = eval("(" + func_txt ")" );
```

---

```js
var func_txt = "function object_123(){\
   object_123_Action();\
   my_clicked(obj);\
}";

this.func = eval("(" + func_txt + ")");
var obj = "...";

function object_123_Action() {
  alert(1);
}

function my_clicked() {
  alert(2);
}


this.func();
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you very much, when I make the changes to pass the object as the param. it works just as I need it - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your functions in an array on the object.
 Then, loop though the functions in another function and execute them.

```
var myObj = { 'myfunctions': [ ] };
```

and to add functions:

```
myObj.myFunctions.push (function () { /*function code here*/ });
```

Or if you already have a named function:

```
myObj.myFunctions.push (nameOfFunction);
```

And to call all the functions, use this function (don't add this function to myObj)

```
function executeMyFunctions (myObj) {
    for (var i = 0; i  < myObj.myFunctions.length; i++) {
        myObj.myFunctions[i]();
    }
}
```

And if it's possible to [avoid using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), you should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function parseStringToFunction(func) {
    func = func || '(function(){return null;})';
    return (new Function('return ' + func)());
};

var stringifyFunction = '(function(a, b) { return a+b; })';

var callStringifyFunction = parseStringToFunction(stringifyFunction)(1, 2);
alert(callStringifyFunction); // results is 3
```

Also read this out: [detail about eval() and new Function()](http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
$("<script type='text/javascript'></script>").html(func_txt).insertAfter($("script"));
```

Comment: Firstly, that's jQuery and the OP doesn't mention jQuery (no jQuery tag).  Secondly, that would insert the script after every single script tag, if there are many, and not at all if there are none.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
assert( eval("(function(a, b) { return a+b; })")(1, 2) == 3 )
```

See: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#eval_as_a_string_defining_function_requires_(*and*)_as_prefix_and_suffix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#eval_as_a_string_defining_function_requires_(_and_)_as_prefix_and_suffix)

Simply wrap the function in parens.